# Powershell 5.1 Workflow not retrying

Tags: powershell, workflow

I'm trying to learn Workflows to process some long running steps. I have to use Powershell 5.1 for various reasons. I really like what I've learnt so far, Workflows can definitely reduce the amount of PS code you have to create. One thing that I'm really stuck on is the retry parameter :

```
InlineScript {
    Write-Output "test"
    0/0
} -PSComputerName $computer -PSConfigurationName "testuser" -PSActionRetryCount 3 -PSActionRetryIntervalSec 5
```

Without writing some additional code or using jobs. Can anybody give me some pointers as to why this is failing. I'm trying to force an error but the Workflow just seems to hang and then not retry for a 2nd time.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the remote computer accept WinRM connection ? Firewall can also block a query and leave the script hanging

Comment: thanks for replying :) 
its all on the same subnet and firewalls have been turned off on both sides.

I can run invoke-command without any issues. It seems to connect ok. If I have no errors in runs perfectly. It only hangs when i'm forcing the error. Ideally I just want it to retry the same logic. Do you think something is blocking it?

Comment: If Invoke-Command is working fine then no, nothing is blocking ! Can you try to add a `-ErrorAction` statement at the end of the line ? Or you are trying to run a cmd that is waiting for a confirmation, then you need to use `-confirm:$false` on this specific cmd

Comment: thanks again. Good shout on the confirm:false. At the minute I've just tried to strip it back to just a very simple script as above. Just a simple 0/0 fail. I've tried using various erroraction preferences along with the usual try catch steps both at the Workflow parameter level and/or also within the script itself. I cant help think this is a bug with the workflow system as I can't find much information on the net about it. Have you by any chance used the -PSActionRetryCount before?

thanks for taking the time to come back to me! :)